# Stopping form onSubmit without 'return false;'

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for a cross browser compatible way to stop a form submission **without** returning false.

For example:

```
<form action="..." onsubmit="someFunc(this);">
    ...
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function someFunc(form){
        // do stuff to stop form submission without return false
    }
</script>
```

I've not found a good way to do this, anybody know if its possible?

Edit:
I've tried both `form.preventDefault()` and `window.event.preventDefault()` in `someFunc()`. It seems like neither prevent the form from submitting in firefox (on a mac).

## Solution

It seems like window.event is not available in FF, while it is in Chrome and IE.. thus my previous attempts not working. I solved this by having the first parameter of the function being called in the form's onsubmit to be the event itself. That can then be cancelled.

New form onsubmit looks like so: `onsubmit="someFunc(event, this);"`

Comment: Any particular reason why?

Comment: I'm trying to allow for calling multiple functions in the onsubmit in any order the user wants. That means I can't do 'return someFunc()' as it would need to come last and that is not desirable in some situations.

Comment: Please answer your own question and accept it - don't edit the question and leave it open. Btw there's a simple solution: use an event handler,  don't write js inline.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `event.preventDefault()` function to stop of form from submitting. Here's an of a form being caught before being submitted in Javascript (with some JQuery):

```
$("form").submit(function(event) { // You can change "form" to whatever ID/class your form has
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

**Done it! I've tested it in Firefox and this definitely works**

Here's a link to the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bZx3e/. Here's the HTML:

```
<form id="form"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"/><label for="checkbox">Checkbox</label>
<input type="button" onclick="check();" value="Submit"/></form>
```

And here's the Javascript:

```
function check(){
    if(document.getElementById("checkbox").checked){
        document.getElementById("form").submit();}
    else{}
}
```

So, basically, if the checkbox isn't checked, do nothing and if it is, submit the form. This way you could have all your validation before submitting the form.

Comment: seems this won't work as I would need to bind the function to the submit event before actually submitting the form, which I would rather not do

Comment: Here you go, I've updated my answer with a solution that works!

Comment: Thanks for posting that Xanco. I know you can stop the submission by running a function in the onclick event on the submit button but I would prefer that this all happen in the form's onsubmit event. Particularly because I have a ton of forms that already have the appropriate onSubmit function and I want to change behavior without needing to modify all the actual forms

Comment: Okay... Having another look now

Answer (score 1):

Each event has an Event object associated with it. In the W3C event model, calling [*event.preventDefaut*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event-preventDefault) will prevent the default action from occuring. However, the only way in the W3C model to get a reference to the related event object is to pass it to the function from the associated listener. For an in–line listener:

```
<form onsubmit="someFunc(event)" ...>
```

If you attach the listener using *addEventListener*, then the related event object will be passed to the listener function as the first argument:

```
someElement.addEventListener('click', foo, false);

function foo(eventObject) {
  var target = eventObject.target;  // element on which the click occured
  var currentTarget = eventObject.currentTarget; // Element that called the listener
}
```

However, the listener in the OP is attached in–line and does not pass a reference to the event, so it can't be captured in browsers that only support the W3C model.

It the IE event model, the related event object is available as a property of the window object, so within the function you can do:

```
var event = window.event;
```

But the IE model doesn't support *preventDefault*, however does provide a *returnValue* property that, if set to false, cancels the default action.

So the most cross–browser way without using `return false` would be:

```
<form onsubmit="someFunc(event);" ...>

function someFunc(event) {
  if (event.preventDefault) {
    event.preventDefault();
  } else {
    event.returnValue = false;
  }
}
```

However, it is very much simpler to use *return false* as it has been reliably supported by every browser since about NN/IE 2.